# Python IndexError with importing module

Tags: python

I have below script which was running quite good till date now on the pyhthon 2.7,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Python code Just to list the information from passwd file to obtain diffrent feilds out of it eg: UserName,GUID,UID,HomeDir,Shell etc.
# We will be using File-handling to obtain the Desired data.
# We have used 'Myfh' as a File-handler ,The open() function opens and returns a file handle that can be used to read or write a file in the usual way.
# Here we have '/tmp/passwd' file to get the data from it & 'r' is read-Only option to do it.
# We either used split fucntion to split the ":" from the file and opt for desired feild.

Myfh = open('/tmp/passwd', 'r')

for line in sorted(Myfh.readlines()):
        a = line.strip().split(":")
        """print "User Name: ", a[0]
        print 'User UID: ', a[2]
        print 'User GID: ', a[3]
        print 'User Gecos: ', a[4]
        print 'User HomeDir: ', a[5]
        print 'Users Shell: ', a[6]
        """
        print '| %-17s |%-10s | %-10s | %-28s | %-24s | %-15s |' % (a[0],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6])

# ls -l /usr/bin/python
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8304 Jun 11  2009 /usr/bin/python

# python  labPasssort.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "labPasssort.py", line 20, in <module>
    print '| %-17s |%-10s | %-10s | %-28s | %-24s | %-15s |' % (a[0],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

=============
I feel this not working when i tried to import below two on the python prompt ">>" ..can someone figure out this ...

> > from os import listdir
> >     from os.path import isfile, join

please help i am a beginner ..

Comment: try to use try-except to catch the `IndexError` and print `a` to see what it contains

Comment: What do you mean by `I feel this not working` ?

Comment: The error tells you there is less than 7 items in your list. If you simply `print a` what does it show you? And are you missing `a[1]` or is that intentional?

Comment: @Manish - i mean to say that when i ran those commands on the python prompt like below.. after thats its not working..

`>> from os import listdir`

`>> from os.path import isfile, join"`

Comment: @Brad .. same script is working on the other Servers right now , when i am testing that.

Comment: `@Ayush - how to catch the IndexError, i mean how i can put thats into my script`

Comment: `Print a` and `print len(a)` as debugging steps...try and see if you can catch any error yourself...and are you skipping `a[1]` intentionally ?

Comment: @Iron - Yes , `thats intentionally`...as that feild contains password section which i dont want to display.

Comment: Fine, what `print len(a)` gave you?..is it consistent on each `line` of Myfh` ?

Comment: Just a note, the line `#!/usr/bin/python` should be the first line in the script. Imports should follow it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the length of `a` is 7?
Because that error mean that you are trying to access an item that exceeds the length of the list.

Print `a` for viewing the real length.

Comment: how to test that? yes the length is 7.

Comment: @Karn...I told you in my comments above, to `print len(a)` just after `a = line.strip().split(":")` ..

Comment: @Iron .. It gives 1, see the results below..

`# python  labPasssort.py


1 </>


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "labPasssort.py", line 20, in <module>

    print '| %-17s |%-10s | %-10s | %-28s | %-24s | %-15s |' % (a[0], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6])

IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: ..which means your file has a line with no `:` in it. It could be a blank line.

Comment: I just ran the script on the another Server & it ran quite good..

`# python labpy.py
| adm               |3          | 4          | adm                          | /var/adm                 | /sbin/nologin   |
| ais               |39         | 39         | openais Standards Based Cluster Framework | /                        | /sbin/nologin   |
| apache            |48         | 48         | Apache                       | /var/www                 | /sbin/nologin   |
| avahi-autoipd     |100        | 156        | avahi-autoipd                | /var/lib/avahi-autoipd   | /sbin/nologin   |
`

Comment: I am nor expertise, though i suspect there may be a problem due to import below on the pythons command prompt: because just after doing that i am facing this index issue on the Server..

`>>from os import listdir 



>>from os.path import isfile, join`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time and analysis.... though i got the error as i found the error to "/tmp/passwd" file itself as there were initial few line were corrupted output which unable to read it.. after retrieving a file again script working normal...